# Google sheets query multiple rows in one by multiple criteria

Tags: google-sheets, filter

For example:
Line 1 : 0 abc 16.10.2022 18.10.2022 1500 0 79

Line 2 : 425 abc 17.10.2022 19.10.2022 799 15 145

Line 3: “empty” abc 17.10.2022 20.10.2022 600 0 34

Line 4: 588 “empty” 01.10.2022 12.10.2022 800 30 15

Line 5: 588 dca 02.10.2022 08.10.2022 300 0 35

Output: 2 lines

425 abc 17.10.2022(max date 1) 19.10.2022(max date 2) 2899(sum1) 15(sum2) 258(sum3)

588 dca 02.10.2022(max date 1) 08.10.2022 (max date 2) 1100(sum 1) 30(sum 2) 50(sum3)

Any ideas? Empty =“”.

I am use filter for first 2 columns, and after that vloop, but filter and unique doesn’t give me perfect result (some data is lost).

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
={QUERY(QUERY(FILTER(A1:G, REGEXMATCH(B1:B, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, IF((B1:B<>"")*(A1:A=""), B1:B, )))), 
 "select max(Col1),Col2,max(Col3),max(Col4),sum(Col5),sum(Col6),sum(Col7) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col2"), "offset 1", );
  QUERY(QUERY(FILTER(A1:G, REGEXMATCH(A1:A&"", TEXTJOIN("|", 1, IF((A1:A<>"")*(B1:B=""), A1:A, )))), 
 "select Col1,max(Col2),max(Col3),max(Col4),sum(Col5),sum(Col6),sum(Col7) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1"), "offset 1", )}
```

[image]

could be written as:

```
=LAMBDA(a, b, c, d, e, {
 QUERY(QUERY(FILTER(c, REGEXMATCH(b, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, IF((b<>"")*(a=""), b, )))), 
 "select max(Col1),Col2"&e&"Col2"), d, );
 QUERY(QUERY(FILTER(c, REGEXMATCH(a&"", TEXTJOIN("|", 1, IF((a<>"")*(b=""), a, )))), 
 "select Col1,max(Col2)"&e&"Col1"), d, )})
 (A1:A, B1:B, A1:G, "offset 1",
 ",max(Col3),max(Col4),sum(Col5),sum(Col6),sum(Col7) where Col1 is not null group by ")
```

[image]